# How to display the terminal for a script which runs at startup?

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, debian

I am currently working on a Raspberry Pi. I want to implement a script to run a Python program at startup. I followed the steps given in [this guide](https://debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian). The contents of my script are:

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/launchScript

cd path/to/file
python main.py
```

Although the script successfully runs at startup (file and I/O operations are working), but the terminal window doesn't appear. I am not able to debug any errors at all.

Can anyone help me on how to make the terminal appear so that debugging is possible?

Comment: [This](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up/8735#8735) may help.

Comment: I am still not able to display the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [a forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=80096);

create a `.desktop` file, Ex. `myApp.desktop`

`myApp.desktop` file content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=lxterminal -e "/home/pi/main.py"
Type=Application
```

Than, copy `myApp.destop` to `~/.config/autostart` directory.